MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT filled with NUll for fixed lenght
Can MYSQL GROUP_CONCAT filled with NUll for max lenght?
FOR EXAMPLE
Arch Lisa Maria
Anna NULL NULL

Explanation
Arch Lisa Maria are three rows for group 1
Anna has one for group 2
So fill group by null to make it 3 size
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat

As this is a programming question it belongs on Stackoverflow, but there is already a smiliar (if not duplicate) question there: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13451605/75852.
